# 'hdfs' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, hadoop, installation, hdfs, system-variable

I am following [this](https://brain-mentors.com/hadoopinstallation/) instruction to install `hadoop 3.3.1` on Windows 10 machine, I followed all the steps as it says but when I reached to step 6, after replacing the `bin` folder, it asks to run the following command:

`– Format the NameNode

– Open cmd and type command “hdfs namenode –format”`

And I did, but I received the following error message:

`'hdfs' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I checked my system environment variables and they all seem to be OK as following:

`echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\ProgramData\OpenJDK

echo %HADOOP_HOME%
C:\ProgramData\hadoop`

Also added `C:\ProgramData\OpenJDK\bin` and `C:\ProgramData\hadoop` to system path. But I don't know what is the problem and why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem is that all the installation instructions say that you should replace downloaded `bin` folder with the existing `hadoop/bin` folder, but you shouldn't do that!

In fact you MUST add up the files there are inside the downloaded `bin` folder to the files already exist within the `hadoop/bin` folder. You HAVEN'T delete the previous `hadoop/bin` folder or the files inside.

Comment: You should be using 3.3.1 version winutils, anyway